# How to scale geofence ellipse on MapControl Windows Phone 8.1 C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, maps, scale

I am working on a geofence based C# project and I need to show the area of certain geofences on a MapControl. I tried this by simple adding an ellipse to the map but, it didn't work like it should because the ellipse doesn't scale when the user scrolls to zoom in/out. How can I solve this problem?

my code:

```
pin.Children.Add(new Ellipse()
{
Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
Width = 24,
Height = 24
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MapElements, not the Children's collection for this.